# How do I use a button component from another file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, textbox, components

I have a button component called **Add** from a file called **add.jsx** which is just a "+" button.

I now have a file called textbox.jsx. the "+" button creates a new textbox. Currently the + button is not my Add component.
I don't know how to reference the add component to make it the primary button.

Here is my textbox.jsx code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Textbox extends Component {
state = {
boxtext: "",
addBox: [],
};

handleChange = () => {
// The line below creates a copy of the state, using the spread operator
let fields = { ...this.state.boxtext };
fields = fields + "+";
this.setState({ fields });
};

//Handle box addition click
addTextBox = () => {
const boxAdded = [...this.state.addBox];
boxAdded.push(1);
this.setState({
  addBox: boxAdded,
});
};

render() {
return (
  <div
    style={{
      position: "absolute",
      left: "50%",
      top: "17%",
      transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    }}
    className="form-group"
  >
    <label for="exampleLogicSymbol">Logic Operator</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      className="form-control"
      id="exampleInputLogic"
      aria-describedby="logicHelp"
      placeholder="enter formula"
      onChange={this.props.handleInput}
      value={this.props.content}
    />
    <button onClick={this.addTextBox}>+</button>
    {this.state.addBox.map(() => {
      return (
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          id="exampleInputLogic"
          aria-describedby="logicHelp"
          placeholder="ENTER"
        />
      );
    })}
  </div>
 );
 }
}

export default Textbox;
```

**Here is my Add component code:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Add extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
  return (
  <div
    className="App"
    style={{
      position: "absolute",
      left: "30%",
      top: "19%",
      transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    }}
  >
    <button
      onClick={this.handleAddSymbol}
      className={"btn btn-success btn-sm m-2 p-1 container"}
    >
      +
    </button>
  </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Add;
```

Thank you for any responses, I am a beginner :)

Comment: Import that button the same way you import other components

Answer (score 1):

You should change 2 things on textbox.jsx file and add one function to add.jsx file.
Import "add.jsx" file on the top of the textbox.jsx first (with the right pathname).

```
import AddButton from "add.jsx";
```

You should change button tag with AddButton tag:

```
<AddButton handleAddSymbol={this.addTextBox}></AddButton>
```

You can bind functions and variables with main and extended files with that system.
handleAddSymbol={this.addTextBox} means that you have a function called 'handleAddSymbol' in add.jsx and 'addTextBox' in textbox.jsx file. You should create handleAddSymbol function into add.jsx file and call this.props.addTextBox() function into that function:

```
handleAddSymbol= () => {
  this.props.addTextBox();
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the comprehensive answer, I am just not understanding the third part 100%, what do you mean? (the paragraph you wrote and the handleAddSymbol code)